# wpDataTables formatting within WPClient

Tags: jquery

I'm create a user portal for a client, and I'm having some trouble getting the wpDataTables plugin to retain its proper formatting within the client portal plugin I'm using (WPClient). The table is meant to look like this:

[image: Table working correctly]

But when I put the WPClient shortcode around the table to hide it from everyone but the correct client the table loses its scrollbar and displays "Show 10 entries" several times, like so:

[image: Table working incorrectly]

How can I fix the formatting while leaving the table inside the shortcode?